# Azure SQL character with return to line (the équivalent of \n in SQL)

Tags: string, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database, character

I'm inserting data from Salesforce to Azure SQL incrementally using Python. In the source I have some columns that contains **characters in multiple lines** (with back to new line), as shown bellow:

```
Name
Familly_Name
Age
```

My python code by default generates a '**\n**' for this. And from my part, I have tried to replace it by **CHAR(13)** and **CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)** and **CHAR(10)** but none of them worked; example (bellow) on a simple select on Azure SQL:

```
select 'hi' + char(13) + 'there'
```

Output:

```
hi there
```

What I need is:

```
hi
there
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CHAR(13)` is a carriage return. Most applications will treat that as a new line, but you should really be using `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`, which is a carriage return followed by a line break:

```sql
SELECT 'Hello' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Goodbye' AS WithNewLine;
```

Outputs the below:

```
WithNewLine
-----------
Hello
Goodbye
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ab99f41b4ff02238889e5a8978f095eb)